# How do you test your software on possible sql server deadlocks before production?

Tags: sql, sql-server, deadlock

Imagine that you developed an application that reads/writes/updates/deletes data in SQL Server database.

What tests do you run to see all possible sql deadlocks before putting it into production?

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the basics of testing.
Unit Testing

- Positive test cases, simple test cases that get you started
- Negative test cases, add bad data that fails validations, and check if its been written
- Boundary (dont confuse it with negative), check for all limits, validations, 0, maxint, minint. For gps, check for +90 degrees, -90 degrees, -180 degrees... Basically testing is not as easy as you think. Doing it right is as/more painful than coding.

All the above tests should focus on code COVERAGE (path coverage too, if you have the guts :)).

And yes, you need to test for add, update, remove anomalies, from your system. Do this per table, per connection per relation.

Scale-ability

- Each table, you need to add data from different clients, increase the number of clients until you break. IT MUST BREAK. That is what you can scale to max.

Performance

- Is comparative in nature. You cannot test for performance by itself. It has to be between builds, between competitive product (exactly same data, exactly same hardware, exactly same scenario)

Stress

- Add a lot of data from all sides, concurrently (dont use scale-ability max's here, the intent is "NOT" to break, but to find out if it can deal with a lot of data, users, concurrency.

Reliability

- Here, use normal data, normal scenario that your customer is looking for. And run it over 48/72 hours. The gc's should bot go crazy, memory leaks should not keep growing, performance should be "consistent" (need not be the best). But should not "DROP" over time. Look for "things going bad with time".

Comment: These tests will uncover a lot more than just deadlocks.